# Executemany insert on duplicate key update error: Not all parameters were used

Tags: python, mysql, syntax-error

So I've been trying to execute this query using python 2.7.15 using mysql.connector.
But for some reason it doesn't seem to work and always return the error: Not all parameters were used.

The table updates has one primary key which is 'ID'

This is the query I tried to run this SQL:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO updates (ID, insert_datetime, egroup, job_state) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE insert_datetime = VALUES(%s), egroup = VALUES(%s), job_state = VALUES(%s);"
mycursor.executemany(sql, jobUpdatesList)
```

This is how one array from the jobUpdatesList array looks like:

```
[u'17281725', datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 10, 16, 11, 45, 724000), u'language', u'R', datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 10, 16, 11, 45, 724000), u'language', u'R']
```

I did this because I tought it needed 7 parameters because I have 7 %s

I also tried to use just 4 parameters like this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO updates (ID, insert_datetime, egroup, job_state) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID = VALUES(%s), insert_datetime = VALUES(%s), egroup = VALUES(%s), job_state = VALUES(%s);"
mycursor.executemany(sql, jobUpdatesList)
```

This is how one Array from the jobUpdatesList array looks like:

```
[u'17281725', datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 10, 16, 18, 9, 268000), u'language', u'R']
```

but then I get the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s), egroup = VALUES(%s), job_state = VALUES(%s)' at line 1
```

When I tried to fix this error by replacing VALUES(%s) with '%s' it worked. Except it replaced all fields with %s instead of the value. I also tried it with unquoted %s like: egroup = %s but I get the same error.

I tried lots of things but I can't seem to get it to work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't bind column names using positional parameters; this is the immediate reason why your code is failing.  But, can you tell us what is the logic for what should happen when a duplicate `ID` is inserted?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen At first I need to insert all the newest items if one already exists I want to update the information of that row so that it is up2date again. I also did Insert statements this way and they do work so I assume the problem is with the ON DUPLICATE KEY part.

Comment: I disagree, q.v. my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't possible to use positional parameters to represent actual column names; column names need to be hard coded in the statement for many reasons.  But, I don't see any problem with doing that in your case:

```
INSERT INTO updates (ID, insert_datetime, egroup, job_state)
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    insert_datetime = VALUES(insert_datetime),
    egroup = VALUES(egroup),
    job_state = VALUES(job_state);
```

Or, as Python code:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO updates (ID, insert_datetime, egroup, job_state) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE insert_datetime = VALUES(insert_datetime), egroup = VALUES(egroup), job_state = VALUES(job_state);"
mycursor.executemany(sql, jobUpdatesList)
```

Comment: Yeah this fixes my issue. I tought that the mysql library would replace all %s signs with their respective values in the array because when I quoted them they did work. Hence why I tried using 7 parameters. This makes much more sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Can I somehow do this without naming all that `VALUES(insert_datetime)` things?