# Mysql execute many wont work when add on duplicate

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql, executemany

I have mysql table and I want to run the [`executemany`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) for that table. I want to make sure, if there is duplicate entry, then it should be updated. I wrote query as below with data.

```
a = 'INSERT INTO tabl (switch_id, readiness, message) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE readiness=%s, message=%s'
b = [(12780, 'not_ready', 'StatusDB data', 'not_ready', 'StatusDB data.'),
     (12781, 'not_ready', 'StatusDB data.', 'not_ready', 'StatusDB data.')]
```

When I try to do execute many on these data with `CONN` of my database connection object, it gives error.

```
>>> with CONN.cursor() as c:
...     c.executemany(a, [b[0]])
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 69, in executemany
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, param_list, many=True, executor=self._executemany)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _executemany
    return self.cursor.executemany(sql, param_list)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 83, in executemany
    return self.cursor.executemany(query, args)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 182, in executemany
    return self._do_execute_many(
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 205, in _do_execute_many
    v = values % escape(next(args), conn)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

When I remove the `ON DUPLICATE` syntaxt, it works fine.

```
>>> with CONN.cursor() as c:
...     c.executemany(a[:-49], [b[0][:3]])
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _executemany
    return self.cursor.executemany(sql, param_list)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 83, in executemany
    return self.cursor.executemany(query, args)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 182, in executemany
    return self._do_execute_many(
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 220, in _do_execute_many
    rows += self.execute(sql + postfix)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 153, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 558, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 822, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1200, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 772, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '12780' for key 'tabl.PRIMARY'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 69, in executemany
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, param_list, many=True, executor=self._executemany)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _executemany
    return self.cursor.executemany(sql, param_list)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _executemany
    return self.cursor.executemany(sql, param_list)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 83, in executemany
    return self.cursor.executemany(query, args)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 182, in executemany
    return self._do_execute_many(
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 220, in _do_execute_many
    rows += self.execute(sql + postfix)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 153, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 558, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 822, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1200, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 772, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/home/myuser/var/virtualenvs/venv//lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '12780' for key 'tabl.PRIMARY'")
```

Its giving DUPLICATE error, but ultimately its able to reach to database. While when we use original query, it gives error for paramater.

If I loop through parameter and run `cursor.execute` it works fine with `ON DUPLICATE` syntaxt.

Whey its not able to match all the parameter when we use `executemany` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you can't use parameterized values in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` portion when using executemany.  You have to refer back to a column value that was already given in the `VALUES` clause.

Try this:

```
a = 'INSERT INTO tabl (switch_id, readiness, message) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE readiness=VALUES(readiness), message=VALUES(message)'
b = [(12780, 'not_ready', 'StatusDB data'),
     (12781, 'not_ready', 'StatusDB data.']
```

Also see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52260250/494134

Comment: mysql has deprecated using values like this (though for now it still works in 8.0) in favor of a slightly different syntax; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63609570/mysql-values-function-is-deprecated